# Students of R. Yonah of Girondi

Tags: tractate-megillah, rabbeinu-yonah

The Beis Yosef in Orach Chaim 149 quotes "תלמידי רבינו יונה על מסכת מגילה". I have been unable to locate this sefer, or any mention of it anywhere. Does anyone know of where I can find it, or at least an article that addresses works by the students of R. Yonah?

Comment: silly idea, but did you check if whatever perush is on the rif in megilla (ran i believe) contains whatever it is the beis yosef quotes? maybe it was just mislabeled for him?

Comment: Note that the Beit Yosef here is quoting Mahari Abohab, who is quoting Talmidei Rabbenu Yonah.  It seems that the commentary is lost to us. (Like the commentary to Ketubot, quoted often in the Shitah Mekubetzet.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think anyone disputes that it's the Ran.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the commentary on Mas. Megillah is lost. It's unlikely, but it could show up someday hidden in a larger collection.

As for who the students of R. Yonah were, Zsharkovski's intro to [Hiddushe Talmide Rabbenu Yonah on A"Z, pp. 11-12](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40911&st=&pgnum=11&hilite=) has the following:

> ### תלמידי רבנו יונה
>
> אף שברור הדבר שרבנו יונה ז"ל הוציא תלמידים למאות ואולי גם לאלפים. נוכל
> לקבוע בבירור רק אחדים מהם.
>
> **רבי שלמה בן אדרת (הרשב"א)** ז"ל. הרשב"א, כנראה, למד גם אצל הרמב"ן ז"ל, אולם ברור שרבו המובהק היה רבנו יונה ז"ל. שכן במקום שכותב "מורי
> הרב" סתם, בלי הזכרת השם. המדובר על רבנו יונה ז"ל. (עיין בתשובות
> המיוחסות לרמב"ן סימן קנ"א, ובתשובות הרשב"א חלק ב סימן קי"ב וחלק ג סימן
> ש"ס, ועיין בחידושיו לנדרים ח ע"א ומ"ו ע"א, וכן מובא במקומות רבים
> בספריו).
>
> **רבי יצחק בן אברהם נרבוני** ז"ל היה תלמיד הרמב"ן ורבנו יונה ז"ל. (בפתיחה למאירי לאבות וז"ל: ומתלמידיהם שמענו שמע הרב רבי יצחק בן אברהם
> נרבוני אשר חבר ספר פירוש הרב אלפסי, ותשובות הרמב"ן אליו נדפסו ב"ספרן
> של ראשונים" מאת ש. אסף, ירושלים תרצ"ה, סימניס: קצ"ו, ר"א, ר"ז ור"י)
>
> **רבי הלל בן שמואל** ז"ל, או כפי שקראו לו "**רבי הלל מוירונא**", מחבר ספר "תגמולי הנפש" ועוד. כפי שהוא מעיד בעצמו למד אצל רבנו יונה בברצלונה
> שלש שנים (מכתבו של רבי הלל מובא בטעם זקנים ובקובץ חמדה גנוזה).
>
> **רבי אהרן הלוי (הרא"ה)** ז"ל. (בפתיחה למאירי לאבות שם)
>
> **הראב"ד**. (לא נודע מי הוא הראב"ד שהיה מתלמידי רבנו יונה, ונזכר בספר זכר צדיק לרבי יוסף אבן צדיק כאחד מתלמידיו שנפטר בברצלונה).
>
> **רבי שלמה בן עלי משוריא (או מסריא)** שכתב חידושים כפי שקבל מרבנו יונה. (סדר הדורות ה"א כ"ח)
>
> **רבי מאיר בר יוסף בן אביסרוי**, שכתב חידושים כפי שקבל מרבנו יונה וביניהם את הכת"י לעבו"ז הנדפם בזה. שמו לא הובא בחיד"א וגם לא נזכר בסדר
> הדורות.
>
> יש שמונים גם את **רבי מנחם ב"ר שלמה לבית מאיר (המאירי)** ז"ל בין
> תלמידיו של רבנו יונה. (חיד"א בשם הגדולים, עיין ערך מנחם בר שלמה לבית
> מאיר, בסוף הערך: ודע דרבו של הרב המאירי הוא רבינו יונה וכו') השערה זו
> לא תעמוד בפני הבקורת, כי המאירי בעצמו כותב בפתיחה לאבות וז"ל: "וכן
> בקטליניה אחר הרב הנשיא האברצלוני שמענו שמע הרב הגדול ר' יונה ושמע הרב
> הגדול ר' משה בר נחמן אשר נתפרסמה חכמתם בעולם". מתוך דברים אלה ניכר שלא
> היה רבנו יונה רבו של המאירי כלל, ועיין שם בפתיחה הנ"ל כשהוא מזכיר את
> רבו רבי ראובן בן רבי חיים הוא כותב: "אשר אני היום קטון אצבעותיו
> ומשיירי מעשה ידיו, החכם הכללי אדוני ורבי", וברור כי לו היה רבנו יונה
> רבו לא היה המאירי נמנע מלהזכיר את זאת.
>
> ובאמת נוכל לעמוד על מקור ההשערה ליחס את המאירי כתלמידו של רבנו יונה.
> החיד"א מסתמך בזה על בעל "שער המלך" שכתב בפ"ח מהלכות לולב ח"א וז"ל:
> "מצאתי בשיטת המאירי למסכת עבו"ז מכת"י שכתב משם רבו הר' יונה". ומתוך זה
> דן החיד"א ז"ל כי המאירי למד אצל רבנו יונה. אולם המעיין בספר בית הבחירה
> לעבו"ז לא ימצא שם את המובא בשער המלך בשמו, ואף שאין זו ראיה חותכת, כי
> מלבד שחיבר המאירי את ספר בית הבחירה כספר פסקים על הש"ס חיבר עוד ספר
> חידושים שלא זכינו לאורם, וכפי שהעיד על זה החיד"א בשם הגדולים, אולם אלה
> הדברים המובאים בשער המלך הם באמת אות באות בכת"י ‏ הנדפס בזה, וברור
> שלפני "שער המלך" היה הכתב יד הנוכחי. ולפי זה נקל גם כן לעמוד על טעות
> הדברים שנפלה בזה, כי הכת"י לעבו"ז נתחבר על ידי רבי מאיר בר יוסף. ונחלף
> בשער המלך בשם המאירי, וקרוב הדבר שיד המדפיס היתה בזה.
>
> לא נמנע גם כן מלהביא כאן את הדעה המיחסת את **רבנו נסים בר ראובן
> (הר"ן)** ז"ל כתלמיד לרבנו יונה (סדר הדורות ה"א ק"כ וז"ל: ר"ן הנקרא
> רנ"בר מגליל ברצלוני תלמיד רבנו יונה והרמב"ן), ואף שגם דעה זו קשה
> לקבלה. מכיון שהר"ן חי מאה שנים לאחר פטירת רבנו יונה ז"ל. (סדר הדורות
> שם שמביא שהר"ן חי בשנת ק"כ ורבנו יונה נפטר בשנת כ"ד)

To summarize, he states that even though R. Yonah's students probably numbered in the hundreds possibly even thousands, we are only able to clearly identify some of them. Some of these are known to have been the case more definitively and others are more tenuously identified. They are as follows:

- [R. Shelomo b. Adereth (aka the Rashba)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_ibn_Aderet)
- [R. Yishaq b. Abhraham Narboni](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/isaac-ben-abraham-narbonne)
- [R. Hillel b. Shemuel of Verona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillel_ben_Samuel)
- [R. Aharon ha-Lewi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharon_HaLevi)
- [Rabad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RABaD)
- R. Shelomo b. 'Ali of Syria
- R. Meir b. Yosef b. Abisroi
- [R. Menahem b. Shelomo Meiri (aka the Meiri)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Meiri)
- [R. Nissim b. Reubhen (aka the Ran)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissim_of_Gerona)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is no longer extant, as with many of his works.
https://www.hamichlol.org.il/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%92%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%99#cite_ref-15
https://he.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3293561